# Find the norm of a linear functional on $C[0,1] $

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Find the norm of a linear functional on $C[0,1]$
$l(x) = x(0) + \int \limits_0^1 (2t-1)x(t)dt$ To find the functional norm I need to evaluate and give an example.
I tried to apply the second mean theorem for the integral, but I didn't get any good results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go brute force on it:

If $\Vert x\Vert\leq 1$, then
$$|l(x)|\leq |x(0)|+\int_0^1|2t-1|dt=\frac{3}{2}$$
On the other hand, given $\epsilon>0$, take a $x\in C[0,1]$ satisfying:

- $-1\leq x\leq 1$ on all of $[0,1]$
- $x(0)=1$;
- $x=-1$ on $(\epsilon,\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon)$;
- $x=1$ on $(\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon,1]$

and evaluate $l(x)=\frac{3}{2}\pm 3\epsilon$.