# Find the norm of the following functional in $C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

I found this problem in a excersise list of functional analysis course, and I was wondering how to solve it.

> Find the norm of the functional in $C[0,1]$ which is given by:
> $$f(x)=\int^{1}_{0}x(t^{2})dt-x(\frac{1}{2})$$

Reading the problem the first time, gave me the idea of just use the norm in the space $C[0,1]$ wich would be the norm $\|x\|_{\infty}=\max_{i}|x_{i}|$ and try to find an upper bound with some inequality, but here we have this function $x(t)$, which we don't have any type of information, so I am unsure on how to proceed.

I saw this post [Find the norm of a linear functional on $C[0,1] $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3946878/find-the-norm-of-a-linear-functional-on-c0-1) but if I am honest I don't understand what is done there, specifically what norm are they using, and why are they setting the norm of $x$ to less than one.
Any type of help would be really appreciated, as I am really stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is the bound
$$|f(x)|\leq \|x\|\int_0^1  dt + \|x\|=2\|x\|,$$ and the question is whether we can attain this value. For that, you can need a function $y(t)$ with $\|y\|=1$ such that $|f(y)|=2$ or a sequence of continuos functions $\{y_n\}_n$ (with $\|y_n\|=1$) which get arbitrarily close to that value.

You may define $y_n$ to be piecewise linear and equal to $1$ in $[0,1/2-1/n]$ and $[1/2+1/n,1]$, and equal to $-1$ in $t=1/2$. Then, if I am not wrong,
$$|f(y_n)\geq 1-\frac{2}{n}+1=2-\frac{2}{n}\to 2.$$.

By the way, the norm you should use in $C[0,1]$ is the supremum norm *for functions*, you are using the definition for elements of $\mathbb{R}^p$.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I get the idea:)